# Taxonomy archive with same slug as custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, slug

My head hurts...

Here is what I have:

Custom post type: Our People, slug => **our-people**
Taxonomy: Job Title, slug => **job-title**

I have an archive page for the Our People CPT at **domain.com/our-people**.

I can easily have archive pages for the Job Title taxonomy terms at **domain.com/job-title/{term}**

But I would like to have archive pages for the Job Title taxonomy terms under the our-people slug.

Example:
**domain.com/our-people/managers
domain.com/our-people/crew**

Where managers and crew are terms of the taxonomy Job Title, which is attached the the CPT Our People.

Is there a way to do this? Setting the taxonomy and the CPT to the same slug obviously didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess I need to read up on WP_Rewrite, but I still don't know how/if it is possible for two things (CPT and taxonomy) to share the same slug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two avenues:

- Hardcode rewrite rules for those specific URLs
- Abandon your quest and design a new URL structure

What your asking for cannot be automated efficiently because it would mean 2 rewrite rules that are the same, but are mapped on to different things. The result being that either the post type slug would take precedence, or the job would take precedence, but only one.

E.g. say we had the url our-people/example, is referring to the people 'example' or the job 'example'? Either WordPress will find the person named example, and 404 if it can't ( despite there being one under job. Or it will do it the other way around

## My Recommendation

Change your URL structure to be less confusing and make more sense by nesting them:

```
example.com/our-people/johnsmith
example.com/our-people/jobs/managers
```

do this by setting the rewrite value when you register your jobs taxonomy ( it's okay to use a / )

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the [Custom Post Type Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) plugin -- it does this automatically as part of its feature set (it's a simple checkbox on the Permalinks page).

Answer (score -1):

WordPress doesn't understand your URL, because there is no rewrite rule for it. You have to add custom rewrite rule in case you want to make it working. Read [The Rewrite API: The Basics](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/) article. There is all what you need.